# Jupyter notebook Latex

Tags: math, latex, jupyter-notebook, notation

I need to type a math formula and its notations. The formula works but the notation format is not correct. Could you help me with that? Thank you.

```
$$
(x)\approx\frac{\phi\prime (x)\times(1-p\prime)\times p}
{\phi\prime(x)\times(1-p\prime)\times p +(1-\phi\prime(x)\times 
p\prime\times(1-p)}\\
$$


$$p$$: notation1
$$p\prime$$: notation2
$$\phi$$: notation3
$$\phi\prime$$: notation4
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your notations? Could you give the code in regular latex, or post a picture? Currently, the `notation` bits are being rendered by Markdown and not via Latex which is probably part of the problem.

Comment: I want the notation right align, no dent, one notation a row. Currently the p is  in the first row, notation1 is in the second row, p' is in third row.....I want (row 1: p: notation 1, row2: p': notation2.....)

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `$$` which forces a new line around an equation. Using a single `$` creates an inline expression, which is what you want. So change the code to be:

```
$$
(x)\approx\frac{\phi\prime (x)\times(1-p\prime)\times p}
{\phi\prime(x)\times(1-p\prime)\times p +(1-\phi\prime(x)\times 
p\prime\times(1-p)}\\
$$


$p$: notation1

$p\prime$: notation2

$\phi$: notation3

$\phi\prime$: notation4
```

Alternatively, to break the lines a little better you can use the `<br/>` tag

```
$$
(x)\approx\frac{\phi\prime (x)\times(1-p\prime)\times p}
{\phi\prime(x)\times(1-p\prime)\times p +(1-\phi\prime(x)\times 
p\prime\times(1-p)}\\
$$


$p$: notation1<br/>
$p\prime$: notation2<br/>
$\phi$: notation3<br/>
$\phi\prime$: notation4<br/>
```

You also mentioned right align - for this you'll need to use a `div` and align it, like so:

```
$$
(x)\approx\frac{\phi\prime (x)\times(1-p\prime)\times p}
{\phi\prime(x)\times(1-p\prime)\times p +(1-\phi\prime(x)\times 
p\prime\times(1-p)}\\
$$

<div align="right">
$p$: notation1<br/>
$p\prime$: notation2<br/>
$\phi$: notation3<br/>
$\phi\prime$: notation4<br/>
</div>
```

Note that the latter two solutions will only really work in the live notebook and I presume HTML output (Markdown may work too). If you plan to convert to latex/pdf afterwards then you'll need the first solution or the solution below:

```
$$
(x)\approx\frac{\phi\prime (x)\times(1-p\prime)\times p}
{\phi\prime(x)\times(1-p\prime)\times p +(1-\phi\prime(x)\times 
p\prime\times(1-p)}\\
$$

$\begin{align}
p: notation1
\newline
p\prime: notation2
\newline
\phi: notation3
\newline
\phi\prime: notation4
\end{align}
$
```

With this solution you can have either left alignment (using single `$` around the `align` environment) or centre alignment (using `$$` around the `align` environment) but I don't think you can have right alignment. Plus this way the `notation`s are in maths font rather than regular font, which may not be desired.